# Laravel 5.4 HTTP testing - method seeInElement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In Laravel 5.3 there was a seeInElement method which would check the text inside an element based on a CSS selector.

https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.html#method_seeInElement

In 5.4 this has been moved to Laravel Dusk.

I still use the HTTP Tests with 5.4 ( https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests ) because they're faster for the testing I want to do, but it's now missing this method.

Is there a way to get this back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `laravel/browser-kit-testing` package.  See the upgrade guide here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#testing