# Error in phpunit laravel 5.4

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I need to use unit testing in laravel but they need to download library `laravel/browser-kit-testing`
When i download it tell me they  need  php 5.6 
And i using php 5.4.

```
 public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $this->visit('/home')
            ->seePageIs('/login');
        $response = $this->call('GET', '/dradmin');
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
        $this->visit('/login')
            ->type('mahmoud@mahmoud.com', 'email')
            ->type('123456', 'password')
            ->press('Login')
            ->seePageIs('/home');

    }
}
```

when use `phpunit`

```
Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\UserTest::visit()

/Users/mahmoud310/ecare/tests/Feature/UserTest.php:21
```

I read in other problems 
[Laravel 5.4 HTTP testing - method seeInElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531404/laravel-5-4-http-testing-method-seeinelement)

use command  `laravel/browser-kit-testing` can solve problem

in my case not work

```
Using version ^1.0 for laravel/browser-kit-testing
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package phpunit/phpunit (locked at 5.7.19, required as 4.8.*) is satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.7.19] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 4.8.35
    ...
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 4.8.1
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.0 conflicts with phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects[3.4.3].
    ...
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.0 conflicts with phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects[3.4.3].
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 4.8.* -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.8.0, 4.8.1, ..., 4.8.9].
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (locked at 3.4.3) -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects[3.4.3].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: From your project folder run `./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`

Comment: not work !
show same error

Comment: Did you do `composer install` to install laravel dependency

Comment: yes and composer update last change

Comment: I would suggest if you're not using homestead, you set it up using this guide [Installing HomeStead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead)

Comment: I can use old method in laravel 5.4 after this

Comment: Ofcourse you can

Comment: this for install php7 already download php7 but  problem in laravel/browser-kit-testing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143381/discussion-between-little-phild-and-mahmoud-saeed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type in the terminal

```
composer require laravel/browser-kit-testing --dev
```

Then use the downloaded files in your project

```
use Tests\CreatesApplication;
use Laravel\BrowserKitTesting\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
```

And don't forget to extend from `BaseTestCase`.

#### Sample code

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\CreatesApplication;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Laravel\BrowserKitTesting\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

class UserTest extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
    public $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {


        $this->visit('/home')
            ->seePageIs('/login');
        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`BrowserKit` provides a backwards compatibility layer for Laravel 5.3 style "BrowserKit" testing on Laravel 5.4.

First, install this package:

`composer require laravel/browser-kit-testing --dev`

Next, modify your application's base TestCase class to extend `Laravel\BrowserKitTesting\TestCase` instead of `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase:`

And your `userTest.php` should be something like

```
<?php

  namespace Tests;

  use Laravel\BrowserKitTesting\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

  abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
  {
      use CreatesApplication;

      public $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';

      //your codes here ...
 }
```

Comment: but when enter phpunit show in terminal  : No tests executed !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything with this. Laravel 5.4 needs PHP 5.6 or later ([proof here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/composer.json)) so it doesn't have anything in common with browser kit. The last one Laravel that supports PHP 5.4 was version 5.0 ([proof here)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/composer.json).

So either you don't know what version of PHP you are using or the problem is somewhere else. It shouldn't be possible to install Laravel 5.1+ on PHP 5.4 as you suggested.

Comment: I think `laravel 5.4` is compatible with all `php 5.6+` because Am using `PHP 7.1.3` with `Laravel 5.4` and it works fine

Comment: @LittlePhild Yes it is, but OP wrote he is using PHP 5.4 and this is not supported at all.